# How to make Internet Explorer automatically login in a certain domain

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, authentication

In my IE, when I want to access a SharePoint site, I'm asked for username/password (obviously).

Is there a way to make IE know that, when I access a domain XXX, it should use certain credentials? Even if I have to use a plugin.

I tried Windows Vault, but that doesn't seem to work with IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the domain to the "Local Intranet Sites" in security in IE. That will log in the current user that is logged into the PC.

Comment: The SharePoint site uses a different AD. The current user has no login in the SP site. I would need to use different credentials.

Comment: Actually, adding the domain to "Local Intranet Sites" solved it. IE doesn't use the current logged in Windows user, but uses the user I first logged in into the domain (after checking "Save Authentication"). This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a ADFS server (an Identity Provider) on the domain where your client is. The SAML or WS-Federation tokens issued from your source domain would be trusted by a second ADFS server (the Service Provider).

Here is what would happen when you would visit the SharePoint site:

1. You go to the SP site, "naked" (no kerberos, password or client certificate)
2. You are redirected to your local ADFS server
3. Your browser authenticates with a Kerberos ticket to the local ADFS server.
4. Local ADFS server issues a SAML or WS-Federation token and redirects you back to the "remote" SharePoint site
5. You go to the remote SharePoint site, with a POST containing a WS-Federation token.
6. Seeing the token, and trusting the signature or the source domain, access is granted.

But it is easier said than done. Things to look out for :

- How will you link existing username password based accounts with shiny new ADFS logons ?
- What if there are duplicate user names ?
- Will that break authentication for remote users who are simply using Kerberos (because for them, it is a local SharePoint) ?
- What is the impact should you change the URL so that users go to your ADFS server first ?

+Beware : the ADFS server role in Windows Server 2008 R2 will install ADFS 1.?. Do not use it. Download and install ADFS 2.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is more work than I'm willing to do. :)